# Отправка POST-запроса при помощи JQuery с данными, которые будут обработаны C++ скриптом.

Tags: jquery, post, http, qt, c++

Задача заключается в следующем:
Есть POST-запрос вида:

```
$.post("localhost:1234/", function(data){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Также запущен скрипт на Qt/C++ (используем класс QTCPServer), который слушает порт 1234 и при поступлении данных обрабатывает их и отсылает обратно.
Возможен ли такой сценарий работы?

Comment: да, вполне возможен. я бы только перешел на порт 80 или 8080 (их как бы более принято использовать в подобной ситуации) Djn только QHTTP, если я правильно помню - клиент, а не сервер:)

Comment: @KoVadim,а если localhost заменить на IP-адрес сервера на котором выполняется C++ файл?

Comment: да, может работать. Но вот только если у Вас выполняется с++ файл... то думаю я тут не помогу:)

Comment: C++ скрипт - звучит сурово :)